# How did Rey know what island Luke was on?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, luke-skywalker, rey

At the end of The Force Awakens, the final pieces of the map to find the planet Luke is on are put together. This leads Rey to the planet Luke is on but that is still an entire planet to search. Luke's home does not appear to be easy to spot with a quick fly over and I would guess he has no beacon set up to lead Rey there, so how does Rey know the exact location of Luke's hide out?

Comment: The Force did it.

Comment: So Rey could feel Luke an entire planet away? Is Rey capable enough in The Force to feel that?

Comment: Well, I was kind of joking, but the Force does take people where they need to go.

Comment: Easy. Just look for the most cinematic and well-framed symbolic staircase on the entire planet.

Comment: oh, well fair enough, it just seems like a huge area for a small team to be able to find one very specific island on.

Comment: Well, Leia did feel Han's death across light years. In SW Rebels the inquisitors can sense Kanan and Ezra from vast distances.

Comment: Did we see the rest of the planet? Maybe there is only one island? ;)

Comment: It was the one with Luke Skywalker on top.

Comment: Star Wars ships have scanners that can detect life forms on a planet. Perhaps it helped. Any confirmation from the novelization?

Comment: Same way that Luke found Yoda on Dagobah.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit - He had R2-D2 look a couple of pages ahead in the script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rey already knew where to go because she'd seen the island chain in her dreams

> Those words were still echoing in Rey’s head as she flew the Falcon
> high above Ahch-To. Rocky islands blanketed with beautiful green trees
> jutted from the water that covered the planet. **Rey recognized the
> landscape from her dreams.** She had imagined the place thousands of
> times without realizing it was waiting for her. Rey landed the Falcon
> at the base of the tallest island. A rugged mountain path led from the
> landing pad to a small clearing near the island’s summit.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Force Awakens - Rey's Story](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Force_Awakens:_Rey%27s_Story)</sup></sub>

And from the [film script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens.html) itself;

> so lonely... so afraid to leave... (then, slight smile) At night,
> desperate to sleep... you imagine an ocean. I see it -- I see the
> island...

Comment: This is referenced more suitably in the movie. When Kilo Ren is interrogating Rey 'I see it too, the ocean and the island'.

Comment: @JeremyFrench - Good point. I've added in a script quote.

Comment: @JeremyFrench How is that more suitable? Or did you mean ‘more subtly’?

Comment: Yes subtly was the word.